# How do I Link the following two tables in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models; Employee and Product.
The two tables already have data.
All I need to do is Assign each Employee to a Product(eg. Computer) and then be able to retrieve the data and display it.

Here are the models.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.dispatch import receiver
from more_itertools import quantify
from django.db.models import Sum
    
# Create your models here. 
class Employee(models.Model):
    address = models.EmailField(max_length=100,null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    sec_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)       
    department = models.CharField(max_length= 50,null=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length= 50,null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' - ' + self.department
    
class Product(models.Model):
    model=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    serial=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    hd_size=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    ram=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    processor=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serial + ' - ' + self.model
```

Comment: Use a foreign key. Add `employee=models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` to your `Product` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is create another model with two fields `first_name` and `model`
your new model will something look like this :

```
class AssignLog(models.Model):
    fname = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    model_name = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

make sure to run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

display all the records using this code.

```
from .models import AssignLog  

all_assign_logs = AssignLog.objects.all()
for assign_log in all_assign_logs:
    print(f"Employee Name: {assign_log.fname}")
    print(f"Product Model: {assign_log.model_name}")
```

note : two fields of AssignLog model are objects of your defined models . Access the attributes accordingly .

Comment: Ask any thing in case of problem